# onClick remove object from array in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not able to delete my list from the array, I have also used react update addons but it doesn't not work

**My delete function**

```
deleteTips(item){
  var array = this.state.newTips;
  var index = array.indexOf(item)
  array.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({newTips: array });
}
```

**My render function**

```
{ this.state.newTips.map((item, j) => {
  const nameVal = "tips" + j
  return(
      <div style={{width:"8%","float":"right","marginTop":"10px"}}>    
        <img style={{marginLeft: '10px'}} onClick={this.deleteTips.bind(this, item)}/>
      </div>                                                                                
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying the array that is the state of the component, therefor your setState might not work, since the new state is the same as the old state.

Could you try

```
 deleteTips(item){
   var array = this.state.newTips.filter(function(s) { return s != item });
   this.setState({newTips: array });
}
```